# ColdFusion Rest API not working

Tags: rest, api, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Previously I was running ColdFusion 10 configured with Apache on my localhost. I am using a different machine now and I am now using ColdFusion 11's built in web server. I have imported settings from an archived ".car" file. My app uses ColdFusion Rest services which were working on my previous machine. I have setup the rest service on this new machine and I am using the same service name but with a different absolute path to directory.

for example:
previous directory: - `D:/foo/bar/api/v2`
current directory: - `C:/foo/bar/baz/api/v2`

The rest service is registered and gets refreshed successfully in the ColdFusion Administrator. But when I try to access the API path on localhost, I get this 500 error :

> This page isn’t working
>
> localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
>
> HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Application v2 could not be found. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: ''''